# any help with how to do equations like this or what I can read is greatly appreciated

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$A_f=\frac{A_o}{1+\beta A_o}$$        rearranging for $\beta $

I get $A_f(1+\beta A_o)=A_o$

$A_f+A_f\beta A_o=A_o$

$A_f\beta A_o=A_o-A_f$

$$\beta = \frac{A_o-A_f}{A_oA_f}$$

The book shows, I don't see how they get this?

$$\beta=\frac{(A_o/A_f)-1}{A_o}$$

Answer (score 4):

Has to be

$\beta=\frac{(A_o/A_f)-1}{A_o}$

which you get by diving the numerator and denominator of the expression you get by $A_f$

Therefore a typo